# Jquery Binding and Triggers

Tags: jquery

The Jquery documentation says:

"Triggered events aren't limited to browser-based events, you can also trigger custom events registered with bind."

Exactly how do I do that?

Here's what I want to accomplish:

1. bind a function to a submit event
2. call that bound function with a trigger

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Events/submit](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) and [Events/trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) functions:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
  // form submission logic
});

//...

$('#formId').trigger('submit');
//trigger the submission
```

You could also bind event handlers using the [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind) function:

```
$('#formId').bind("submit", function(){
  // form submission logic
});
```